# Unable to import Snowflake Connector python library after install in Azure Devops YAML Pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-pipelines-yaml

Please help me to resolve this issue.
snowflake.connector is unable to import after it is successfully installed in Azure Pipeline.

**Error::**

```
Installing collected packages: sortedcontainers, pytz, asn1crypto, urllib3, typing-extensions, tomlkit, pyjwt, pycparser, platformdirs, packaging, idna, filelock, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, snowflake-connector-python
Successfully installed asn1crypto-1.5.1 certifi-2024.2.2 cffi-1.16.0 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 cryptography-42.0.5 filelock-3.13.1 idna-3.6 packaging-24.0 platformdirs-3.11.0 pyOpenSSL-24.1.0 pycparser-2.21 pyjwt-2.8.0 pytz-2024.1 requests-2.31.0 snowflake-connector-python-3.7.1 sortedcontainers-2.4.0 tomlkit-0.12.4 typing-extensions-4.10.0 urllib3-1.26.18
Python 3.8.10
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflakepoc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snowflake as sf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'**

**##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.**
```

**Devops YAML Script::**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - snowpipe

variables:
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'


pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: 'Define Python version'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8.x'
      addToPath: true

  - task: bash@3
    inputs: 
      targetType: inline
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      script: |
        python -m venv worker_venv
        source worker_venv/bin/activate
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" snowflake-connector-python
        python --version
        python snowflake.py
    displayName: 'Install Snowflake Python Connector '
```

**I tried to execute Python inline code also. But no luck..**

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run Python Script to Connect to Snowflake'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'inline'
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      script: |
        import snowflake.connector
        print("done")
```

I tried to install the library through VS Code with Python Environment and then import the library snowflake.connector and that was successfully executed.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you descript, you want to import the "**`snowflake.connector`**" module in your Python script (**`snowflake.py`**). From the error message, you seem provided a wrong name of the module in the Python script file.

```
import snowflake as sf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'**
```

The correct module name to be imported should be "**`snowflake.connector`**". Try to update in the "**`snowflake.py`**" file like as below.

```
import snowflake.connector as sfc

. . .
```

---

If you want to import the [**`snowflake`**](https://pypi.org/project/snowflake/) package in your Python scripts to manage Snowflake objects with [Snowflake Python API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/snowflake-python-overview), you also should ensure that you have installed this package into the specified directory ("**`./.python_packages/lib/site-packages`**" for your case).

```
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" snowflake
```

Installing the **`snowflake`** package automatically installs all of its subpackages as dependencies, including the Snowflake Python Connector, the Snowpark Python library, and snowflake.core. See "[**Install the Snowflake Python API library**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/snowflake-python-installing)"

This package also provides the ways to connect to Snowflake in Python. See "[**Connect to Snowflake with the Snowflake Python API**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/snowflake-python-connecting-snowflake)".

---

Comment: Hi @Bright, Thanks for your input. I have tried to install the snowflake package like "pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" snowflake" and the python file with this "import snowflake.connector as sfc". But the error remain same.

  File "snowflakepoc.py", line 4, in <module>
    import snowflake.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

Comment: What is the `snowflakepoc.py` file? Is it written by you (or your team)? If you try to run the Python project on your local machine, does the same issue occur?

Comment: Ensure you have set your Python project to correctly import the required module from the specified directory ("`./.python_packages/lib/site-packages`").

Comment: Hi Bright... snowflakepoc.py file is written by me. Which is having python scripts including snowflake.connector. and i have installed under that specified directory ("./.python_packages/lib/site-packages") only.

Though I have changed the process little bit now and that got success. I have installed snowflake.connector from python script file (snowflakepoc.py) using 'subprocess' and then import that. Instead of installing the python library from YAML, I have installed that from python script itself.

Comment: @Abhijit, It is recommended to install all the required packages before you run the Python scripts. As far as I know, before the Python tool starts to execute the scripts, it will first validate the scripts, including to verify the required packages.